# Load an URL different from config.xml using loadUrl method

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I'm using Cordova 5.1 with the following plugins:

```
# cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.2.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"
org.apache.cordova.media 0.2.16 "Media"
```

I need to be able to load (for testing) a different URL than the one in my config.xml at runtime.

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    ...
     launchUrl = "http://google.com";
     Log.d(TAG, "Loading URL into web view: " + launchUrl);
     loadUrl(launchUrl);
  }
}
```

How would I do that? I have seen examples of using CordovaWebViewClient but there is no way of setting an instance of this class on the web view that I'm using in my app.

The above example loads the URL into a chrome instance and not my app.

Since I'm using crosswalk for the WebView I tried to use

```
class ResourceClient extends XWalkResourceClient {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(XWalkView view, String url)     
  { 
  ..
  }
}
```

and set on the view using setResourceClient(). shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not called.

This was done in this method:

```
@Override
protected CordovaWebViewEngine makeWebViewEngine() {
    CordovaWebViewEngine cordovaWebViewEngine = super.makeWebViewEngine();

    XWalkWebViewEngine xwe = (XWalkWebViewEngine)cordovaWebViewEngine;

    XWalkCordovaView swv = (XWalkCordovaView)xwe.getView();

    swv.setResourceClient(new ResourceClient(swv));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following method of XWalkCordovaView instead of loadUrl(launchUrl):

```
XWalkCordovaView swv = (XWalkCordovaView)xwe.getView();
swv.load(launchUrl, null);
```

XWalkCordovaView extends XWalkView so you can use XWalkView methods to debug. More details in [Javadoc](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v5/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html#load(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).